# problem in sending and receiving data between Android app and php

Tags: java, php, android

I'm having a problem sending data from Android app to php page...I have in the android side a button that takes me to this activity:

```
public class Post extends Activity {

public void postData(View v){
     //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.67/phptester/insertdata.php"); 
        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(4);

        try {
            // Add your data
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("descr", "Fire"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "1.333"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", "1.333"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());



        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
}
```

}

And this is my php code:

```
  <?php
   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

   mysql_select_db("locationdb", $conn);

   if (isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST['descr']) && isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']))
   {
     $id = $_POST["id"];
     $descr = $_POST["descr"]; 
     $lat = $_POST["lat"];
     $lon = $_POST["lon"];

     $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (ID, Description, lat, lng) VALUES('6', '$descr', '1.666', '1.666')");

     echo "data inserted";
     mysql_query($query);

}

else {

    echo "Not data was intered ".mysql_error() ;
}

?>
```

The problem that is killing me is that there is no data being stored in that database and i don't know why!!!! it seems like the php can't get data from the Android app....Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution but will help you see what data the server sends back to your app, and therefore help you debug the issue.

```
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
Log.i("myapp", "Reply from server: " + response);
```

Now, nything you `echo` back from your PHP script will be printed out in the Android log, which may make it easier to work out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try some troubleshooting (make sure `logfile` is writable):

```
file_put_contents('logfile', print_r($_POST, true)."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Also log errors from the database:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ...';
mysql_query($query) or
   file_put_contents('logfile', 'DB error: '.mysql_error()."\nQuery: ".$query."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```